# Ajax call to web services in razor

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

this is my web service call:

```
 <wsdl:operation name="upload">
 <soap:operation soapAction="http://uri.org/IDA_Command/upload" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and this is my web service call from javascript:

```
  var uploadInputs = "/Import/uploadInputs ";
  $.get(uploadInputs + "/", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (value, key) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://uri.org/IDA_Command/upload',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response = true) {
                    alert("Inputs uploading...");
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("There was an error in uploading the inputs..");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here, iam passing 'value and key' as parameter for 'upload', but code does not returns 'success' or 'failure' alert message, Also iam not getting any error.. How do i know that the service method get called? or iam missing something inside the code.

Can anyone tell me, how to call the upload method with two parameters in service using Ajax call? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a failure calling the service but you won't be able to catch it because you have an incorrect failure handler.

Change `failure:` by `error:`

```
error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the mistake i did inside the code, to call service method.

Comment: @Ravi Shankar: change what I suggest and you'll see error handler to be called. Inspect method parameters to see what's wrong. You can also see if there is any error on browser console

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Iam getting the error alert message. could you pls tell me Is there any way to acheive the sucess or iam missing something inside ajax?

Comment: @Ravi Shankar: create you error handler like this `error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }` and put a breakpoint inside to explore parameters values. That should give you an idea of what's wrong